# about LWUIT supported mobiles

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, lwuit

Hey I have built a small application  using LWUIT and I want to know which mobile devices does support LWUIT framework? Can anyone help me regarding this issue and share their knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

LWUIT is supported on `MIDP 2.0/CLDC 1.1` and up, has been ported onto CDC platforms, other mobile and embedded devices.

Read this article for your reference, [Portability and Performance of LWUIT.](http://download.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/cehefjdi.html)

Comment: Yeah. Samsung corby is `MIDP 2.0` version.

Comment: Hi bharath! Long time. Pls do you know if LWUIT is still supported by mobile phones now? Specifically Android. I'm aware of CodeNameOne, but I'm not referring to that, just the old LWUIT. Thanks